# If I restart my game, will my friends stay on my list?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I plan on re-starting my Pokemon X and Y, and I have a lot of Friend Safaris/Friends. If I re-start my game, will I keep my friends on my friends list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your friends will stay on your friend list, even if you re-start your saves of Pokemon X/Y.

This is because Friend Safari is linked to your 3DS' Friend Code and your console's friend list. This is also why you can see your friends who don't own Pokemon in Safari.

But keep in mind that all the abilities/gifts/pets obtained by friends will be lost, because they are tied to your save.

Comment: Unless the question was edited very quickly after posting, I believe you mean "yes" instead of "no."

Comment: Thank you for noticing, It was 9AM and I was too tired staying up all night.

Comment: What do you mean by Pets?

Comment: Pokemons you owned